# Mediapipe Python - link landmark with handedness

Tags: python, mediapipe

I'm trying to create a rectangle around each hands, using Mediapipe in python.
I can't understand how I can link the handedness (Left or Right) with the landmarks.

```
results = hands.process(image)
hand_landmarks = results.multi_hand_landmarks
handedness = results.multi_handedness
```

From hand landmarks I get 21 landmarks for each hand (so 42)
And from handedness I get the info about right or left
Since in handedness I get no reference about the coordinates I cannot link this info. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the idx of the landmarks and handedness lists are linked..  e.g. idx 0 is for the same hand.  So.. if you enumerate over one of them the current index of the enumerated list will get you the associated information from the other..

Something like below would give you the Right or Left assessment of the hand in lbl.  Note that the handedness assessment assumes the image is in mirror mode so it may need to be flipped to get handedness to work as expected.  The Classification access hard index is likely a kludge on my part..

```
for idx, handLms in enumerate(results.multi_hand_landmarks):
    ...
    lbl = results.multi_handedness[idx].classification[0].label
```